# Unity 3d. Force quads instead of triangles in mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

Hi i am making video player in Unity that allows to move corners of the screen. I am using plane mesh as a screen. I found the way to move all vertex proportionally to the vertex on the corner. However when i move it, image is splited diagonally and don't look right. Question is how to prevent that? I was thinking, maybe if i would be able to force quads instead of triangles it would look good, if it is possible of course. I will appreciate any suggestion.

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

Comment: You can't .. every GameEngine I know is based on triangles, quads are always split into two triangles ... that's how computer graphics works...

Comment: Even systems that deal in quads (say, Minecraft) its just hiding one of the edges from you. A quad is just two triangles welded together.

Comment: So, maybe there is a way to remap video player to the plane somehow?